# Android widget: how to set listener on buttons on widget?

Tags: android, events, button, widget

I have searched between many questions others asked about this problem and all were confusing and not helpful.

My problem is I make widget for app, and it starts ok, but it doesn't react on events. I have 2 buttons on widget. Here is the source for class implementing it.

```
public class MediaPlayerWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static final String NEXT_SONG = "1";
public static final String PLAY_PAUSE = "2";
private MediaPlayerActivity act=new MediaPlayerActivity();

private void addEvents(Context ctxt) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, MediaPlayerWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(PLAY_PAUSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, intent, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_play, pi);
    intent=new Intent(ctxt,MediaPlayerWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(NEXT_SONG);
    pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_next, pi);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt,Intent i){
    String cmp=i.getAction();
    if(cmp.equals(NEXT_SONG)){
        act.nextSong();
    }else if(cmp.equals(PLAY_PAUSE)){
        act.playPause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager mgr, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    addEvents(ctxt);
}


 }
```

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem? I have seen some other solutions with Service doing refresh but since I have 2 buttons I don't need such thing. If any other code is needed I will supply it.

EDIT:

If you don't know what's wrong with code above, can anyone tell me or give some sample code on how to implement button listener/event in widget.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions:
1) Check your manifest whether receivers are registered.

2) Try creating a different intent object for each action.

I have similar problems that solved. If these 2 didn't work, post some more about your code and I'll try to help.

Comment: I registered it properly, but i think intent is not working properly. I will try to find other solutions.

Comment: So did u tried out creating a different intent object? For each button, try to use a different intent object. You are using the same object right now for NEXT_SONG and PLAY_SONG.

Comment: Nope nothing happened, i got pissed off and removed widget. :P You know any good tutorial or e-book on this?

Comment: Try this: http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/                                  You'll understand the flow easily and this post may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298888/android-music-player-widget

Comment: And also post your entire code so that I can look on it and might let you know about the problems.

Comment: I am busy right now but i will try this definitely, it looks promising!